# Using const inside React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

In React, inside a functional component is it a good practice to use a **props** array to filter it and assign to a **const** and use that without setting the **const** value to a **useState**. In this case i don't have any state updation inside the component.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: can you add your code also

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you are not triggering a rerender, we use states to  trigger a rerender on the components, either a change in the component state or a change in the props.

Comment: The component gets props from parent and there is no state changes specific to the child. For example there is no events and just need to render the filtered prop in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is perfectly fine and means you do not have to manage your state on a component update. For example, if a filter parameter would change.

However, just realize you are filtering on each render. Compared to a single time if you would store the variable in state as you mentioned.